# Optimizing for Modulo Queries

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have a use case where I want to be able to query tens of thousands of records for the modulo of a certain field value with another number, i.e. queries like

`SELECT * FROM EVENTS WHERE MOD(OFFSET)=5`

What are some performance considerations, if any, I should have in place to ensure that my queries are more efficient? Are there any specific kinds of indexes that would speed up this kind of querying?

Has there been a published comparative analysis or benchmark or some kind that has been done for these kinds of queries between various databases? Alternatively, is there a naive way of determining what choice of database would be best suited for this kind of querying?

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you can use an [index on the expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html):

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON events (mod(offset, 5));
```

Only works for *that* number, of course. And `5` would be a bad example, because ~ 20 % of the rows would qualify for each possible value, and an index starts paying off for ~ 5 % selected rows or fewer. Otherwise, a sequential scan will be faster.

Aside: `offset` is a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Don't use it as identifier.

Comment: The number would not be constant unfortunately